# Does Kodi 19 "matrix" support hardware acceleration for Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: video, kodi

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 (8 GB) model overclocked to 2Ghz, and I want to run Kodi on top of Kali. I have it set up with version 19, but there is clearly no hardware acceleration, (indicated by choppy playback and extreme CPU usage). I can however play videos smoothly without any CPU spikes in VLC. Also, there is no option to enable hardware acceleration in kodi settings > player > video, as suggested by many sources.

I have found people using kodi with hardware acceleration, but the common observation is they all are running Version 18.

Do I need to downgrade or is there a way to enable hardware acceleration somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem was that there is a special Raspberry Pi package for kodi, only available through the bullseye repository, and I had installed it from the kali repo.

So, it now works with hardware acceleration as it is the package from bullseye.

Comment: You should post your new question as a new question.  Not in an answer.